# How is the configuration of Google Analytics 4 with AMP?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4, asynchronous-messaging-protocol

I understand that recently a release came out informing that GA4 is AMP compatible, that an extra configuration must be done, putting the following

```
`'ampHost' tag: '${ampdocHost}'`
```

in the amp configuration variables, but there is another step that is: **"Register the ampHost custom parameter in Google Analytics 4 and relaunch your AMP page"** This step I can't understand. Where in GA4 should this configuration be done? How should it be done?

Answer (score 0):

You must add it in "Custom definitions". Try this:

[image: Step 1]

[image: Step 2]

Comment: I did the implementation but I don't notice an increase in Analytics metrics Would something else be missing?